Flutter code does not open in Android Studio E/AndroidRuntime(23949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Flutter code does not open in Android Studio
E/AndroidRuntime(23949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(23949): Process: com.android.application, PID: 23949
E/AndroidRuntime(23949): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.application/com.android.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.application.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.application.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~iXAnX6a9vdUz4tmXDKPM-Q==/com.android.application-2ZDoD7mz9RqSs7rXmH0yhQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
E/AndroidRuntime(23949):    ... 12 more

I want to solve this problem, I already tried to clean flutter and fix firebase but nothing works.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check AndroidManifest.xml: Verify that your MainActivity is correctly declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file under the  tag. It should look something like this:
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
android:configChanges="..."
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>


My AndroidManifest.xml is the same as what you showed, is there any other place where this error could be?

@NicolasMontovani this is the only thing which can cause you app to throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException . If you need more help then you need to post your AndroidManifest.xml file.
